# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React-RCTAnimation":

Tags: javascript, react-native, cocoapods

When trying to run `pod install` in my iOS folder on my React-Native project, I get the following error:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React-RCTAnimation":
> In Podfile:
> React-RCTAnimation (from `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation`)
> Specs satisfying the `React-RCTAnimation (from` ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I have tried using `pod deintegrate` running `pod install` again, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your error message is what I'd focus on: "Specs satisfying the React-RCTAnimation (from ../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target." This just means the library you're trying to use, React-RCTAnimation, requires a higher minimum deployment target than what's currently set. Check the iOS Deployment Target set in your Podfile and raise it to a higher version, then try again. This is most easily done through Xcode.